# Error in library(rela) : there is no package called ‘rela’

Tags: r

I am tying to get the rela package installed on my home computer. When trying install.packages("rela") I get a message:

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Haven't been able to find much help through online resources.

Answer (score 2):

Try `remotes::install_version("rela", version="4.1")` (you'll have to `install.packages("remotes")` first).

Answer (score 1):

First, try to download one of the versions of the package: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rela/

Then, install the package by providing the path of the .tar.gz file downloaded

[image]